# How to get Microsoft Timzone with a city name and country name?

Tags: .net, timezone, datetimeoffset

I am not sure whether it is possible. I am simply storing MS timzone info for a local time to my SQL database. 
There is a way I can provide a city name and country name by the user. 
but i want my system be able to tell the timezone that city is in by MS Timezone definition.

No Noda Time suggestion please. I love that approach, but I though use case is simpler than what Noda for.

The time I am storing is a event time. Which means, a sport event happened, I would like to store its origin timzone and storing the actual UTC time in another column.

Thanks.

Comment: A sample of what you are looking for would be helpful in understanding your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigation, This is nearly impossible for the time being.